# populate a dropdown in the cq5 dialog using servlet

Tags: java, servlets, aem

ere is my dropdown widget structure,

```
    <chooseselect
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    name="./sel"
                    options="/bin/demoslingservlet.json"
                    type="select"
                    xtype="selection">

    re</chooseselect>
```

Im able to hit  the below servlet,and code in servlet is below:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse   response) throws ServletException, IOException
{

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
HashMap hashMap1 = new HashMap();
HashMap hashMap2 = new HashMap();

hashMap1.put("A", 10L);
hashMap2.put("B", 20L);
jsonArray.put(hashMap1);
jsonArray.put(hashMap2);

json.put("jsonarray", jsonArray);
PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
    printWriter.print(json);
    printWriter.flush();
    }
```

Im able to see the output **{"jsonarray":[{"A":10},{"B":20}]}** in the response, but how to render this response to the dropdown in the dialog.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format in which you are populating the options is wrong.
The [options](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/widgets-api/?class=CQ.form.Selection) for selction should be in the following format

```
[
    {
        "value": 10,
        "text": "A"
    }, {
        "value": 20,
        "text": "B"
    }
]
```

Try to generate the above format like this

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
TidyJSONWriter json = new TidyJSONWriter(writer);
json.array();
/* loop through your options and create objects as shown below */
json.object();
json.key("text");
json.value("A");
json.key("value");
json.value(10);
json.endObject();

json.object();
json.key("text");
json.value("B");
json.key("value");
json.value(20);
json.endObject();
/* end your array */
json.endArray();
response.getWriter().write(writer.toString());
```

Your selection widget would then display the json in the dropdown.

Comment: Hi, even though, you have configured two values in the json, somehow only the first value is getting rendered in the dropdown,for your information, Im using JSONWriter instead of TidyJSONWriter, seems something wrong from my side,but thanks for your quick response Rakhi

Comment: I had populated only 1 object initially. It was only for reference. Anyways added the second one too, to avoid confusion. Basically i mentioned to loop through your list containing the data, and populate the values as shown above.